# Carregar o bytecode da imagem em String e converter para Bitmap no Flash AS3

Tags: string, imagem, bytecode, actionscript-3

Estou precisando carregar os bytecodes da imagem dentro de uma `String` e depois converter para `Bitmap`. Estou utilizando o código abaixo mas sem sucesso:

```as
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("imagebytecode.txt"));
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loaded(e:Event):void {

   var str:String = urlLoader.data;
   var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
   byteArray.writeUTFBytes(str);
   var bitData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100);
   var rec:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
   bitData.setPixels(rec, byteArray);
   var bit:Bitmap = Bitmap(bitData);

}
```

Quanto eu codifico a imagem para `Base64` e a abro utilizando a biblioteca do Steve Webster, funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

O próprio flashplayer possui uma classe para você converter uma string no formato base64 e também, tem uma classe para fazer o processo inverso.

No seu caso, esse código não funcionou, por que você precisa decodificar (ou interpretar) a string.

Eu não testei o exemplo abaixo mas este é o caminho que você deve seguir

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("imagebytecode.txt"));
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loaded(e:Event):void
{
    var str:String = urlLoader.data;
    var base64:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder;

    // decodifica e adiciona o resultado no buffer
    base64.decode(str);

    // obtem uma amostra em bytes do resultado
    var bytes:ByteArray = base64.toByteArray();

    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 100);
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rect.width, rect.height);

    // escreve a amostra dentro do bitmap data
    bitmapData.setPixels(rect, bytes);

    // e finalmente, a imagem
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Jan Cássio!

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não ajudou. Veja o seguinte procedimento que eu quero fazer: "ByteCodeImagem -> String -> Bitmap = dá errado". Quando eu faço "ByteCodeImagem64 -> String -> Decodificar64 -> Bitmap funciona"! Outra observação é que a classe Base64Decoder infelizmente é para Flex e eu estou utilizando Flash que não usa o pacote mx.utils. Mesmo assim obrigado!

Comment: Neste caso, você pode usar qualquer Base64 para AS3, da uma olhada nesta classe, acho que ela tem tudo que você precisa. https://gist.github.com/burakkirkil/4051420

Comment: Desculpe mas não é uma imagem Base64 que estou querendo transformar em String e depois em Bitmap e sim uma imagem comum. Eu citei esta codificação pois quando eu a utilizo funciona normalmente e não tenho dúvidas em relação à esta biblioteca. Mesmo assim obrigado!