# Salvar no banco de dados o conteúdo binário de uma imagem

Tags: php, mysql, upload

Como faço para pegar o **bytecode** de uma imagem na hora do upload para poder armazenar ela no campo blob do mysql sem a necessidade de salvar a imagem em ftp?

Comment: Bytecode de imagem? Bytecode ou conteúdo binário?

Comment: Não serve a imagem salva temporariamente no HD, que vem por padrão? Bastaria você armazenar ela no BLOB, que o PHP descarta o arquivo sozinho, se você não usar o `move_uploaded_file`. Dá pra pegar do STDIN, mas aí você teria que processar ela pra separar do resto do `multipart`, que é bem mais complicado.

Comment: @Thomas bytecode mesmo, seria mais ou menos isso mas a função inversa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5326/carregar-o-bytecode-da-imagem-em-string-e-converter-para-bitmap-no-flash-as3

Comment: Imagem normalmente não tem _bytecode_. A não ser que você esteja falando de uma imagem de máquina virtual ;) (_bytecode_ se refere a um código intermediário pré-compilado, que não é nem o executável, nem o fonte. comum em Java, por exemplo)

Comment: @Bacco pegue qualquer imagem do seu computador e clique em abrir com bloco de notas, sabe esse monte de caractéres estranhos que ele mostra? então é isso o que eu quero.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinho Esse é o conteúdo binário da imagem. Bytecode é outra coisa.

Comment: Eu entendi, você quer o conteúdo binário da imagem. Sugestão, em vez do bloco de notas use o **[HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)** (gratuito), que ele mostra em hexadecimal, quando vc quiser analisar um arquivo. De qq forma, como eu comentei, seria mais fácil vc salvar do HD pro BLOB, ou usar o STDIN. Mas lembrando que por STDIN, se ela vier por form upload, vem com um monte de "sujeira" que nao vai ser do seu proveito.

Comment: @Bacco Isso garoto, mas eu quero pegar esse "conteúdo binário" com o php, talvez usando algum comando ou biblioteca.

Comment: Isso aqui pega tudo que o browser enviou: **[http-get-request-body](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-get-request-body.php)** ou isso: `$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');`. Só que vem com cabeçalhos, _boundaries_, etc, e ainda você teria que reverter o encoding dos dados. Muito chato de fazer. Ainda acho melhor vc pegar do HD mesmo, jogar no BLOB e deixar o PHP deletar automático (a velocidade é praticamente a mesma, e HD nao desgasta tao rapido assim a ponto de você querer economizar gravação e deleção). Mas vamos ver se aparece alguém que conheça uma _lib_ pronta.

Comment: @Bacco blz, mas vc acha que eu deveria mudar o titulo e tirar bytecode e por outra coisa no lugar?

Comment: Ah, eu acho que não custa nada melhorar né, fica tecnicamente mais correto. Não que isso seja um problema sério, mas como editar é simples, acho que cai bem. Só não entendi ainda qual seria um bom motivo pra você não querer usar o método normal do PHP, mas isso ja é outra questão. Voltando à questão da edição, é bom pois os comentários sobre o assunto também ficarão obsoletos.

Comment: E se você usar Base64 para converter a imagem?

Comment: cara, se liga, vc já tem 3 respostas que são válidas e está dando downvote pra todo mundo!!! Dei up pra não desmoralizar quem se deu ao trabalho de te responder >-(

Comment: @andre eu não estou acompanhando mais essa pergunta, os downvotes não são meus... devem ser do cara que colocou minha pergunta em recompensa Lollipop

Comment: Fiz edição para um novo título mais apropriado ao contexto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você quer é simplesmente salvar uma imagem em BD, segue sugestão de como fazer:

**Listagem 1: Script de criação da tabela no banco**

```
CREATE TABLE PESSOA (  
    PES_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
    PES_IMG BLOB  
);
```

**Listagem 2: Formulário de upload**

```
<form action="gravar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <label for="imagem">Imagem:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="imagem"/> <br/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/> 
</form>
```

**Listagem 3: Script de gravação da imagem no banco**

```
<?php 
$imagem = $_FILES["imagem"]; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "test"; 

$acesso = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';db=' . $db; 

// Recebeu a imagem
if($imagem != NULL):
    $nomeFinal = time().'.jpg'; 

    // Tenta gravar o arquivo no servidor
    if (move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'], $nomeFinal)): 

        // Pega a imagem
        $tamanhoImg = filesize($nomeFinal); 
        $mysqlImg = addslashes(fread(fopen($nomeFinal, "r"), $tamanhoImg)); 

        // Conecta-se ao BD e tenta gravar
        try{
            $pdoConecta = new PDO( $acesso, $username, $password ) ;
            $pdoConecta->query("INSERT INTO PESSOA (PES_IMG) VALUES ('$mysqlImg')");
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        // Apaga o arquivo
        unlink($nomeFinal); 
    endif;

else:
    echo"Você não realizou o upload de forma satisfatória."; 
endif;
?>
```

**Fonte**: http://www.devmedia.com.br/upload-de-imagens-em-php-e-mysql/10041

Comment: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo `mysql_*`?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/3635)

Comment: @guilherme-nascimento o ideal é o uso de mysqli_ ou de classes como o PDO, por questões de segurança e desempenho. Particularmente eu prefiro o PDO, posto que trabalho com programação orientada a objetos. O acima foi apenas uma transcrição da fonte mencionada, mas o destaque está na lógica e não nos métodos.

Comment: Agora que vi que era um link e não uma pergunta. Agradeço o link. Porém volto a frisar que não uso nem mysql e muito menos gravação de imagens em BD... apenas agilizei para o parceiro localizar algo que lhe fosse de ajuda. Mas fique a vontade para editar a minha resposta ;)

Comment: Pequenas melhorias sim, mudar o código completamente (conforme a minha sugestão) eu discordo, a não ser que seja feito pelo autor, que é você no caso. Então o caso certo é fornecer dicas (que nem estou fazendo)

Comment: Vou lista algumas sugestões: 1. Faça tratamento de erro no `fopen`. 2. não use `time()` e não grave o arquivo no mesmo local do script, prefira gravar em uma pasta isolada ou `/tmp` 3. não feche o `} else  ` assim, use isto `} else { ... }`, se alguem que usar o código errar um caractere poder ocorrer um erro (prefira padronizar o estilo da tipagem), leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51002/3635

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões. Fiz algumas modificações. Outras não achei necessário já que o objetivo é dar apenas uma idéia de como gravar a imagem em BD, e não dar todo o código pronto. ;)

Comment: Como disse em outro comentário, aqui você não deve necessariamente só tentar ajudar o individuo especifico, mas sim agregar conteúdo a comunidade, ou seja tornar a sua resposta uma fonte útil para a comunidade e não só para um individuo :) Outra dica `@` não é legal :( mas acredito que a resposta já seja aceitável, espero que não me entenda mal Boa sorte

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se o que você quer é o array de bytes para salvar no banco aqui está como fazer:

```
$filename = "myFile.sav"; 
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb"); 
$fsize = filesize($filename); 
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize); 
$byteArray = unpack("N*",$contents); 
print_r($byteArray); 
for($n = 0; $n < 16; $n++)
{ 
    echo $byteArray [$n].'<br/>'; 
}
```

Mas lembre como o php é sincrono arquivos grandes podem levar muito tempo para serem processados.

Veja mais em [na fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963110/php-read-file-as-an-array-of-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

O que você procura não é binário, é [base64](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php).

Com essa função você pode transformar a imagem em um formato que você pode salvar no banco e usar no HTML de forma fácil. No entanto o base64 ocupa 1/3 de espaço a mais, ou seja, você vai ocupar mais espaço em disco no seu servidor e , mais importante, sua página vai demorar mais pra carregar.

Utilização:

```
$imgEmBase64 = base64_encode($_FILES['nomeDoCampo']['tmp_name']);
$sql = "insert into banco (imagem) values( '" . mysql_real_escape($imgEmBase64). "')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Você também pode transformar esses dados em arquivos de imagem e salvar no servidor, mas ai seria mais fácil aceitar o upload de imagens mesmo.

Comment: Salvar em base 64 é uma bela gambiarra nesse caso, pois o MySQL suporta os dados originais numa boa. Você está deixando o arquivo ocupar mais espaço à toa. Chega a ser mais errado do que addslashes (que já é um erro também, o mysql tem função específica de escape)

Answer (score -1):

"Como faço para pegar o **bytecode** de uma imagem na hora do upload para poder armazenar ela no campo blob do **mysql** sem a necessidade de salvar a imagem em **ftp**?"

Na pergunta tem varias coisas. Enviar imagens no servidor pode ser feito usando um software FTP (Fetch, Cyber duck...) o usar o sistema de "upload" (input type file, exemplo aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

No caso do FTP vc coloca a imagem (o documento), onde vc quer. Depois vc deve indicar ao PHP onde esta a imagem, para fazer o tratamento.

No caso do "upload", o servido coloca a imagem numa pasta "tmp". Usando a função PHP MoveUpload file (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php) vc deve colocar a imagem numa outra pasta.

O tratamento: se o objetivo e somente resolver um problema tipo "curiosidade", acho melhor enviar em FTP (mas fácil). Depois, ler a imagem usando fopen(), colocar os dados numa "string" e fazer um INSERT num BLOB.

Se o objetivo e "usar", é diferente. Um BLOB não e "dentro" a tabela, mas é um "documento" fora da tabela, isso significa que SQL deve abrir este documento (e lento). Também, se vc tem uma tabela com BLOB para imagems, quando vc vai tentar fazer SELECT *, vc vai certamente usar mas memoria do que tem SQL. E o resultado vai também ser lento.

O que fazemos, geralmente e colocar somente o "path" para buscar a imagem. Por exemplo "my_pict.jpg" num Varchar.

Mais fácil, mas podemos chegar na frente de um outro problema: como fazer para colocar minha imagem, mas impedir o uso desta imagem a partir de um outro servidor? (um outro web site que quer usar minha imagem sem autorização por exemplo).
Op 1: colocar um htaccess que impede a leitura
Op 2: colocar numa pasta "inacessível". Isso depende do hospedagem que vc tem, mais nos hospedagem que eu tenho, eu pouso colocar dados "antes" da pasta "www". Os documentos são invisível a partir do Web, mas eu posso ler eles a partir de PHP.

Minha opinião: bem pensar o "porque" antes de buscar o "como".

Answer (score -1):

Depois de feito o POST, voce pega a variável do upload e salva o arquivo uma pasta temporária qualquer, para voce poder ler o arquivo e salvar o conteúdo na variável **$imagem** do php para depois voce salvar no banco de dados (campo do tipo BLOB do MySQL).

```
<?php
           $path = "images/arquivo_temporario";
           if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem'][['tmp_name'], $path))
            {
                $handle = fopen($path, "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $size);
                $imagem = base64_encode($content);
                fclose($handle);
            }
?>
```

Repare que foi usado a **função base64_encode** ao invés de **addslashes** (muito usado nos exemplos da internet), pois facilitará posteriormente a exibição da imagem em HTML, além de nao alterar o conteúdo do arquivo.

**Observe que ao usar addslashes**, função que retorna uma string com barras invertidas antes de caracteres que precisam ser escapados para serem escapados em query a banco de dados, **voce estará alterando o conteúdo do arquivo.**

Uma vez salva no banco de dados, voce pode ler a imagem salva e guarda-la na variável **$imagem** do php para poder exibi-la com seguinte código HTML com PHP:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $imagem;?>"
```