# O que causa o "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file"?

Tags: php

Ao incluir este método a um código PHP

```
<?php
function meuMetodo($a, $b) {
   $c = $a + $b;
   if ($c > 1) {
      return TRUE;
   } else {
      return $c;
}
?>
```

Ocorre este erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in Z:\web\project1\lib.php on line 10

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Isto ocorre geralmente quando esquecemos de fechar uma `{` (chave, chaveta, brace ou curly bracket).

No caso do código, está assim:

```
<?php
function meuMetodo($a, $b) {
   $c = $a + $b;
   if ($c > 1) {
      return TRUE;
   } else {
      return $c;
}
?>
```

Quando o correto é isto:

```
<?php
function meuMetodo($a, $b) {
   $c = $a + $b;
   if ($c > 1) {
      return TRUE;
   } else {
      return $c;
   }//Faltou este
}
?>
```

---

Segue série de motivos que podem ocasionar o erro "unexpected end":

### Falta da chave (chavetas) de fechamento:

```
<?php
if (condição) { 
     echo 'Olá mundo'; 
?>
```

### Falta do ponto e vírgula no final:

```
<?php
if (condição){ 
    echo 'Olá mundo'
} 
?>
```

### Falta de fechar as aspas ou apóstrofo antes do `;`:

```
<?php
    echo "Olá mundo;
?>
```

### Apóstrofo faltando:

```
<?php
    echo 'Olá mundo;
?>
```

### Falta de um parêntese:

```
<?php
    metodoChamado(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'xyz';
?>
```

### Misturar tags PHP (`<?php`) com short_open_tag (`<?`):

> Claro que isto só vai ocorrer se o servidor estiver com o short_open_tag desligado no `php.ini` e não será sempre, depende de como usou, teste o exemplo a seguir:

```
<?php
if (true) {
?>
oi
<? /*aqui é um a short_open_tag */
}
?>
```

> No caso do short_tag note que a primeira parte abre o if com `{`, mas como o que esta dentro de short_open_tag `<? ... ?>` não é executado, então o PHP não reconhece o `}`

---

### A importância da indentação

Algo que pode ajudar a não esquecer de fechar é a [indentação](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Em tipografia, indentação é o recuo de um texto em relação a sua margem. Em ciência da computação, indentação (recuo, neologismo derivado da palavra em inglês indentation) é um termo aplicado ao código fonte de um programa para ressaltar ou definir a estrutura do algoritmo.

Na maioria das linguagens de programação, a indentação é empregada com o objetivo de ressaltar a estrutura do algoritmo, aumentando assim a legibilidade do código.

Código *sem* indentação:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
if ($a > 0) {
if ($a > 10) {
$a = 0;
}
echo $a;
}
?>
```

Código *com* indentação:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
if ($a > 0) {
    if ($a > 10) {
        $a = 0;
    }
    echo $a;
}
?>
```

Assim é possível organizar a "posição" das chaves (chavetas) e ter a facilidade na leitura para ver se ficou faltando alguma chave (chavetas) de fechamento.

> **Nota:** Em uma única linguagem de programação, podem existir diversos tipos de indentação, isto é uma escolha um tanto quanto pessoal, mas todas ainda tem o mesmo intuito, o de facilitar a leitura.

Comment: Muito completo. Boa

Comment: @Miguel obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Outra possibilidade é quando se usa [short tags](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) e o servidor não está configurado para aceitá-las.

*Obs.: Não é o caso dessa pergunta, mas fica para referências futuras.*

Short tags:

```
<?
    echo 'Foobar';
?>
```

Ao invés de:

```
<?php
    echo 'Foobar';
?>
```

Note que a tag que abre o bloco tem `php` após a interrogação.

Comment: Testei agora e o erro **não** ocorre se *short tags* estiverem desligados `short_open_tag=Off`, na verdade ele é interpretado apenas como texto normal. Obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: Consegui encontrar exatamente como pode ocorrer a falha com short_open_tag, editei a resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/51003/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Verifique o formato do arquivo.
Foi assim que resolvi o erro

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file"

depois de sofrer um pouco.

Use um editor de arquivos como o `Notepad++`, na barra de ferramentas, clique no botão "*exibir todos os caracteres*" e também observe no rodapé do editor no lado direito o formato do arquivo, `DOS/Windows`, `Unix` ou `Macintosh`.

Para servidores em ambientes `UNIX (Linux)`, no fim de cada linha do arquivo deve ter um [`LF`] apenas. [`CR`][`LF`] também funcionam, mas estes são do ambiente DOS/Windows.

Para servidores Windows (`IIS` por exemplo) tem que ter um [`CR`][`LF`] no fim da linha.

Para servidores Macintosh tem que ter apenas um [`CR`] no fim da linha.

Comment: Mac não usa `[CR]` isso era só até o *Mac OS 9* e ele já não é usado desde 2002, o núcleo do Mac passou a ser like-unix, e usa `[LF]`. Sobre scripts em PHP é indiferente usar `[CR]`+`[LF]` ou `[LF]`, o interpretador PHP simplesmente ignora isso, a unica diferença é se usar dentro de `echo`, `var_dump`, `print`, `print_r`, mas só afeta o **output**, a interpretação e execução do script não sentem diferença, o que você deveria ter era um caractere "NULO" ou um `[BS]`.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, se você esquecer de colocar o nome da function dá esse erro também. Por exemplo:
jeito errado que gera esse erro:

```
function(){
     //vai gerar esse erro como se tivesse faltando chave '}'
}
```

Jeito correto:

```
    function nome(){
     //ok 
    }
```

Parece mentira que alguém pode esquecer do nome da função. Mas acontece.

Comment: Sim também, mas esquecer um `)` ou `}` é comum, agora esquecer o nome de uma função inteira é **bem improvável**, a não ser que acidentalmente tenha apagado, ainda sim ser for um *Closure*, provavelmente terá o delimitador `;` (ponto e virgula).

Comment: No javascript é possível criar função sem nome. Pode confundir.