# Alguem pode ajudar com esse codigo

Tags: php

Estou tentando por um site com servidor local para edição mais estou com esse erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\classes\configphp.php on line 29

ja tentei seguir algumas sugestões aqui encontradas no site mais sempre da o mesmo erro.

```
<?php
if(!defined('INITIALIZED'))
    exit;

class ConfigPHP extends Errors
{
    private $config;
    private $loadedFromPath = 'C:\Ot\';

    public function __construct($path = false)
    {
        if($path)
            $this->loadFromFile($path);
    }

    public function loadFromFile($path)
    {
        if(Website::fileExists($path))
        {
            $content = Website::getFileContents($path);
            $this->loadedFromPath = $path;
            $lines = explode("\n", $content);
            unset($lines[0]); // remove <?php
            unset($lines[count($lines)]); // remove ? >
            $this->loadFromString(implode("\n", $lines));
        }
        else
            WebsiteErrors::addError('#C-4', 'ERROR: <b>#C-4</b> : Class::ConfigPHP - PHP config file doesn\'t exist. Path: <b>' . $path . '</b>');
    }

    public function fileExists($path)
    {
        return Website::fileExists($path);
    }

    public function loadFromString($string)
    {
        $ret = @eval('$_web_config = array();' . chr(0x0A) . $string . chr(0x0A) . '');
        if($ret === false)
        {
            $error = error_get_last();
            new Error_Critic('',  ' - cannot load PHP config from string', array(
            new Error('MESSAGE', $error['message']),
            new Error('FILE', $error['file']),
            new Error('LINE', $error['line']),
            new Error('FILE PATH', $this->loadedFromPath)
            ));
        }
        $this->config = $_web_config;
        unset($_web_config);
    }

    private function parsePhpVariableToText($value)
    {
        if(is_bool($value))
            return ($value) ? 'true' : 'false';
        elseif(is_numeric($value))
            return $value;
        else
            return '"' . str_replace('"', '\"' , $value) . '"';
    }

    public function arrayToPhpString(array $a, $d)
    {
        $s = '';
        if(is_array($a) && count($a) > 0)
            foreach($a as $k => $v)
            {
                if(is_array($v))
                    $s .= self::arrayToPhpString($v, $d . '["' . $k . '"]');
                else
                    $s .= $d . '["' . $k . '"] = ' . self::parsePhpVariableToText($v) . ';' . chr(0x0A);
            }
        return $s;
    }

    public function getConfigAsString()
    {
        return self::arrayToPhpString($this->config, '$_web_config');
    }

    public function saveToFile($path = false)
    {
        if($path)
            $savePath = $path;
        else
            $savePath = $this->loadedFromPath;
        Website::putFileContents($savePath, '<?php' . chr(0x0A) . $this->getConfigAsString() . '?>');
    }

    public function getValue($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->config[ $key ]))
            return $this->config[ $key ];
        else
            new Error_Critic('#C-5', 'ERROR: <b>#C-5</b> : Class::ConfigPHP - Key <b>' . $key . '</b> doesn\'t exist.');
    }

    public function setValue($key, $value)
    {
        $this->config[ $key ] = $value;
    }

    public function removeKey($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->config[ $key ]))
            unset($this->config[ $key ]);
    }

    public function isSetKey($key)
    {
        return isset($this->config[ $key ]);
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->config;
    }

    public function setConfig($value)
    {
        $this->config = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você fez isto:

```
private $loadedFromPath = 'C:\Ot\';
```

Mas quando usou `\` você escapou o `'`, o correto seria:

```
private $loadedFromPath = 'C:\Ot\\';
```

Leia mais sobre o erro "Parse" em:

- [Script retornando Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51003/3635)

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma string não terminada na linha 8. Use:

```
private $loadedFromPath = 'C:\Ot\\';
```