# Erro "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('"

Tags: php

O sistema gera uma sequência de números aleatórios e dependendo da combinação desses números a sequencia vai ser inserida em uma das duas tabelas
a tabela de sequencias ruins e a de sequencias boas
eu fiz esse script mas tá faltando algum detalhe pois está dando o erro

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php on line 24

```
<?php
set_time_limit(10000);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());}
mysql_select_db("test");

for ($x = 0; $x <= 1000000; $x++) {
$D1  = (mt_rand(1,3));$D2  = (mt_rand(1,3));$D3  = (mt_rand(1,3));
$D4  = (mt_rand(1,3));$D5  = (mt_rand(1,3));$D6  = (mt_rand(1,3));
$D7  = (mt_rand(1,3));$D8  = (mt_rand(1,3));$D9  = (mt_rand(1,3));
$D10 = (mt_rand(1,3));$D11 = (mt_rand(1,3));$D12 = (mt_rand(1,3));
$D13 = (mt_rand(1,3));$D14 = (mt_rand(1,3));$D15 = (mt_rand(1,3));   

if(
( $D1==$D7 && $D7==$D8 && $D8==$D9 && $D9==$D5 ) || ( $D11==$D7 && $D7==$D8 && $D8==$D9 && $D9==$D15 ) || ( $D6==$D2 && $D2==$D3 && $D3==$D4 && $D4==$D10 ) || ( $D6==$D12 && $D12==$D13 && $D13==$D14 && $D14==$D10 ) || ( $D6==$D7 && $D7==$D8 && $D8==$D4 && $D4==$D5 ) || ( $D10==$D9 && $D9==$D8 && $D8==$D2 && $D2==$D1 ) || ( $D11==$D12 && $D12==$D13 && $D13==$D9 && $D9==$D10 ) || 
( $D15==$D14 && $D14==$D13 && $D13==$D7 && $D7==$D6 ) || ( $D1==$D2 && $D2==$D3 && $D3==$D9 && $D9==$D10 ) || ( $D5==$D4 && $D4==$D3 && $D3==$D7 && $D7==$D6 ) || ( $D1==$D7 && $D7==$D13 && $D13==$D9 && $D9==$D5 ) || ( $D11==$D7 && $D7==$D3 && $D3==$D9 && $D9==$D15 ) || ( $D1==$D7 && $D7==$D3 && $D3==$D9 && $D9==$D5 ) || ( $D11==$D7 && $D7==$D13 && $D13==$D9 && $D9==$D10 ) || ( $D6==$D2 && $D2==$D8 && $D8==$D4 && $D4==$D10 )
( $D6==$D12 && $D12==$D8 && $D8==$D14 && $D14==$D10 ) || ( $D1==$D2 && $D2==$D3 && $D3==$D4 && $D4==$D5 ) || ( $D6==$D7 && $D7==$D8 && $D8==$D9 && $D9==$D10 ) || ( $D11==$D12 && $D12==$D13 && $D13==$D14 && $D14==$D15 )
)
{
$query = "INSERT INTO candypot_best (D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, D11, D12, D13, D14, D15) VALUES ('$D1','$D2','$D3','$D4','$D5','$D6','$D7','$D8','$D9','$D10','$D11','$D12','$D13','$D14','$D15')";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

}
else
{
$query = "INSERT INTO candypot_lose (D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, D11, D12, D13, D14, D15) VALUES ('$D1','$D2','$D3','$D4','$D5','$D6','$D7','$D8','$D9','$D10','$D11','$D12','$D13','$D14','$D15')";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

}


 //   echo "The number is:   $D1 ,  $D2 , $D3 ,  $D4 ,  $D5 , $D1 ,  $D6 , $D7 ,  $D8 , $D9 , $D10 , $D11 , $D12 , $D13 , $D14 , $D15<br>";
} 



//if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $result)) {
//    echo "New records created successfully";
//} else {
//    echo "Error: " . $result . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);}
//
//mysqli_close($conn);



?>
```

Comment: Boa tarde, recomendo que faça titulos intuitivos. Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51002/3635

Answer (score 2):

Pelo erro de sintaxe retornado na linha 24, está faltando um comparativo `||` na sua condição:

**Trecho de sua condição**

```
( $D6==$D2 && $D2==$D8 && $D8==$D4 && $D4==$D10 )
( $D6==$D12 && $D12==$D8 && $D8==$D14 && $D14==$D10 )
```

**Resposta**

```
( $D6==$D2 && $D2==$D8 && $D8==$D4 && $D4==$D10 ) ||
( $D6==$D12 && $D12==$D8 && $D8==$D14 && $D14==$D10 )
```