# Erro unexpected end of file no cakephp

Tags: cakephp, xampp

Estou com um projeto em cakephp que está na versão 1.3.15 e estou tentando rodar no Xampp mas está dando esse erro como o print em anexo e essa linha corresponde ao fechamento da minha tag html.
Alguém sabe como eu devo proceder?
[image: Erro unexpected end of file]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="<?php echo Configure::read('CurrentLanguage.locale'); ?>">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/logos/<?php echo $siteConfig['Configuration']['logo_path_color'] ?>/apple-touch-icon-iphone.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/logos/<?php echo $siteConfig['Configuration']['logo_path_color'] ?>/apple-touch-icon-ipad.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/logos/<?php echo $siteConfig['Configuration']['logo_path_color'] ?>/apple-touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" />
    <title> <?php echo ( isset( $page_title ) ) ? $page_title . ' -' : ''; ?> Arquidiocese de São Sebastião do Rio de Janeiro - ArqRio </title>
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="3 days" />
    <meta name="language" content="portuguese" />
    <meta name="distribution" content="Global" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="rating" content="General" />
    <meta name="dc.language" content="pt" />
    <meta name="geo.country" content="Brasil" />
    <meta name="author" content="Phocus Interact - www.phocus.com.br - (12) 3942.5384 - @phocusinteract" />
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="FBDcdDwU0aGZTYbNJu3SZ6beOFTLi7auLLnZIUmF9l4" /> 
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#875fb0"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="<?php echo $this->base ?>/headerLogo.png"/>
    <meta name="title" content="<?php echo ( isset( $page_title ) ) ? $page_title . ' -' : ''; ?> Arquidiocese de São Sebastião do Rio de Janeiro - ArqRio" />
<?php


    if ( isset( $data['meta_tags'] ) ) {
        echo '<meta property="keywords" content="' . $data['meta_tags'] . '" />' . "\n";
    } else {

        if($this->params['controller']=="news" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="Dom Orani, Arcebispo, Papa, Bento XVI, Arquidiocese, Rio de Janeiro, JMJ, Rio 2013, ArqRio, cultura, religião, internacional, São Sebastião, testemunho, fé, notícias, jornalismo" />
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="article_interviews" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="artigos, formação, espiritual, colunistas, padres, arcebispo, Dom Orani, salvação, jovens, famílias, ano da fé, João Paulo II, Bento XVI" />
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="events" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="eventos, festas, católico, arquidiocese, Rio de Janeiro, Niterói, comemoração, folia com cristo, São Sebastião, agenda, arcebispo, Dom Orani, bispos, missa, programação, novena, confraternização" />
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="events" && $this->params['action']=="event_by_principal"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="eventos, festas, católico, arquidiocese, Rio de Janeiro, São Sebastião, agenda, arcebispo, Dom Orani, missa, programação, novena, confraternização" />
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="social"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content=" JMJ, jornada mundial da juventude, jovens, sonho, união, evento, santo, papa, João Paulo II, Bento XVI, 2013, Brasil, discípulos, nações, cruz, Rio2013, redes sociais, facebook, twitter, pinterest, flickr" />
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="vicariatos"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="vicariatos, vigários, ArqRio, Arquidiocese, Rio de Janeiro, São Sebastião, Jacarepaguá, Leopoldina" />
        <?

        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="quemsomos"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="Arquidiocese, São Sebastião, Rio de Janeiro, bispos, arcebispo, brasão das armas." />
        <?

        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="oarcebispodomorani"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="arcebispo, Dom Orani, Tempesta, história, arquidiocese, bispo, Cisterciense, Rio de Janeiro, São Sebastião, portalum, continente digital do povo de Deus" />
        <?

        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="search_results"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content=" arcebispo, arquidiocese, bispo, capela, cristão, Dom Orani, fé, igreja, jesus, padre, paróquias, religião, rio de janeiro, são sebastião, vida, Deus, Cristo, catedral, comunhão" />
        <?

        }else if($this->params['controller']=="churches" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="igrejas, capelas, bairros, rio de janeiro, históricas, copacabana, leblon, lapa, laranjeiras, aterro, glória, mangueira, manguinhos, tijuca, botafogo, flamengo, urca" />
        <?

        }else if($this->params['controller']=="contacts" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="keywords" content="contato, fale conosco, sugestões, arquidiocese, dúvidas, arqRio" />
        <?
        } else {
            echo '<meta property="keywords" content="' . $siteConfig['Configuration']['site_meta_tags'] . '" />' . "\n";
        }
    }

    if ( isset( $data['meta_description'] ) ) {
        echo "\t" . '<meta property="description" content="' . $data['meta_description'] . '" />'  . "\n";
        echo "\t" . '<meta property="og:description" content="' . $data['meta_description'] . '" />'  . "\n";
    } else {

        if($this->params['controller']=="news" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Central de últimas notícias sobre Dom Orani, Papa Bento XVI, Arquidiocese, JMJ Rio 2013, ArqRio, cultura, religião no Brasil e no mundo." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Central de últimas notícias sobre Dom Orani, Papa Bento XVI, Arquidiocese, JMJ Rio 2013, ArqRio, cultura, religião no Brasil e no mundo."/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="article_interviews" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Central de formação e artigos direcionados à família, jovens e conteúdos espirituais. " />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Central de formação e artigos direcionados à família, jovens e conteúdos espirituais. "/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="events" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Agenda completa do Arcebispo Dom Orani e bispos eméritos. Além de toda programação de eventos católicos do Rio de Janeiro." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Agenda completa do Arcebispo Dom Orani e bispos eméritos. Além de toda programação de eventos católicos do Rio de Janeiro."/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="events" && $this->params['action']=="event_by_principal"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="eventos, festas, católico, arquidiocese, Rio de Janeiro, São Sebastião, agenda, arcebispo, Dom Orani, missa, programação, novena, confraternização" />
            <meta property="og:description" content="eventos, festas, católico, arquidiocese, Rio de Janeiro, São Sebastião, agenda, arcebispo, Dom Orani, missa, programação, novena, confraternização"/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="social"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Mashup de tudo o que acontece nas redes sociais sobre a Jornada Mundial da Juventude no Rio de Janeiro em 2013." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Mashup de tudo o que acontece nas redes sociais sobre a Jornada Mundial da Juventude no Rio de Janeiro em 2013."/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="vicariatos"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Endereços e todas informações sobre os Vicariatos da Arquidiocese do Rio de Janeiro." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Endereços e todas informações sobre os Vicariatos da Arquidiocese do Rio de Janeiro."/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="quemsomos"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Conheça mais sobre a Arquidiocese de São Sebastião do Rio de Janeiro, sua estrutura, bispos, arcebispo e seu brasão." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Conheça mais sobre a Arquidiocese de São Sebastião do Rio de Janeiro, sua estrutura, bispos, arcebispo e seu brasão."/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="oarcebispodomorani"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Arcebispo Dom Orani João Tempesta - Que Todos Sejam Um. História e passagens sobre o Arcebispo da Arquidiocese do Rio de Janeiro." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Arcebispo Dom Orani João Tempesta - Que Todos Sejam Um. História e passagens sobre o Arcebispo da Arquidiocese do Rio de Janeiro."/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="pages" && $this->params['action']=="search_results"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Busque e encontre tudo sobre conteúdo católico do Rio de Janeiro e do Brasil. O maior acervo de notícias, vídeos, conteúdo de formação e agenda católica você só encontra na ArqRio." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Busque e encontre tudo sobre conteúdo católico do Rio de Janeiro e do Brasil. O maior acervo de notícias, vídeos, conteúdo de formação e agenda católica você só encontra na ArqRio."/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="churches" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Encontre qualquer igreja ou capela do Rio de Janeiro. Lista com endereços, bairros e mapa de como chegar." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Encontre qualquer igreja ou capela do Rio de Janeiro. Lista com endereços, bairros e mapa de como chegar."/>
        <?
        }else if($this->params['controller']=="contacts" && $this->params['action']=="index"){
        ?>
            <meta property="description" content="Dúvidas, Sugestões, Críticas ou Solicitações? Fale com a ArqRio." />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Dúvidas, Sugestões, Críticas ou Solicitações? Fale com a ArqRio."/>
        <?
        } else {
            echo "\t" . '<meta property="description" content="' . $siteConfig['Configuration']['site_description'] . '" />'  . "\n";
            echo "\t" . '<meta property="og:description" content="' . $siteConfig['Configuration']['site_description'] . '" />'  . "\n";
        }
    } 

?>
<?php if ( $this->params['controller'] == 'pages' && $this->params['action'] == 'index' ) { ?>
<meta property="og:image " content="<?php echo $this->base ?>/headerLogo.png"/>
<?php } ?>
<meta property="og:title" content=" <?php echo ( isset( $page_title ) ) ? $page_title . ' -' : ''; ?> Arquidiocese de São Sebastião do Rio de Janeiro - ArqRio "/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ArqRio - Arquidiocese de São Sebastião do Rio de Janeiro" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo URL . $this->params['url']['url']; ?>" />
<meta name="p:domain_verify" content="7263cb0399209d3d50f273146b7ac27e" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1086424376" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="<?php echo Configure::read('CurrentLanguage.locale'); ?>" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/logos/<?php echo $siteConfig['Configuration']['logo_path_color'] ?>/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logos/<?php echo $siteConfig['Configuration']['logo_path_color'] ?>/favicon.png" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php 
    $version = "";
    // $version = "?v=" . strtotime("now");

    echo $html->css('main.css' . $version, 'stylesheet', array('media' => 'screen,print'));
    echo $html->css('tiles.css' . $version, 'stylesheet', array('media' => 'screen,print'));
    echo $html->css('dynamic_content.css' . $version, 'stylesheet', array('media' => 'screen,print'));
    if (isset($page_name)) 
    {
        if( isset($page_additional_css) )
        {
            foreach($page_additional_css as $current_css)
            {
                $current_css = is_array($current_css) ? $current_css : array('name' => $current_css, 'media' => 'screen');

                echo $html->css($current_css['name'], 'stylesheet', array('media' => $current_css['media']));
            }
        }

        $file = new File(CSS_URL . $page_name . '.css');
        if ($file->exists()) 
        {
            echo $html->css( $page_name . ".css" . $version );
        }
    }

    if( isset( $this->params['url']['print'] ) )
    {
        echo $html->css('print', 'stylesheet', array('media' => 'screen,print'));
    }
    else
    {
        echo $html->css('print', 'stylesheet', array('media' => 'print'));
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseURL = '<?php echo $this->base; ?>';
    var baseURLAllPath = '<?php echo URL; ?>';
    var baseURLLanguage = baseURL + '/<?php echo Configure::read('CurrentLanguage.short'); ?>/';
    var featureOrder = <?php echo (isset($featuresOrder["FeatureConfiguration"]["data"])) ? $featuresOrder["FeatureConfiguration"]["data"] : '""' ?>;
</script>
<?php
    echo $javascript->link('plugins/jquery-1.8.2.min');
    echo $javascript->link('plugins/jquery.event.drag-2.2');
    echo $javascript->link('plugins/jquery.easing.1.3');
    echo $javascript->link('plugins/jquery.mousewheel');
    echo "<!--[if lt IE 9]>";
    echo $javascript->link('plugins/html5shiv');
    echo "<![endif]-->";
    echo $javascript->link('plugins/jquery.cycle.all');
    echo $javascript->link('main.js' . $version);

    if( isset($page_additional_js) )
    {
        foreach($page_additional_js as $current_js)
        {
            echo $javascript->link($current_js . ( strpos($current_js, "http") === false ? ".js" . $version : "" ) );
        }
    }

    if (isset($page_name)) 
    {
        $file = new File(JS_URL . $page_name . ".js");
        if ($file->exists()) 
        {
            echo $javascript->link($page_name . ".js" . $version); 
        }
    }
?>
<?php echo $javascript->codeBlock($siteConfig['Configuration']['analytics_code']); ?>
<?php // FOURSQUARE ?>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(){window.___fourSq={'uid':'15351651'};var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.src='http://platform.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js';s.async=true;var ph=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];ph.parentNode.insertBefore(s,ph);})();</script>
</head>
<body <?php if( isset($page_category) ) echo "class=\"$page_category\""; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->element('social_codes'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->element('header'); ?>
    <section class="content">
        <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
    </section>
    <?php echo $this->element('footer'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Print de Erro]

Comment: Tem como colocar isso como código? pode ser a falta de um `;` ou o fechamento de uma `{`. Possível duplicata de [Script retornando Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51002/91)

Comment: O código é esse acima e no final de tudo tem o </body> e o </html> que por algum motivo, não está aparecendo.

Comment: Pode evidenciar a linha do erro e a anterior?

Comment: Como assim, @rray? Vc quer que destaque a linha do erro? É a </html>

Comment: Coloquei o print na pergunta, @rray

Comment: @rray.
Pf, vc tem alguma sugestão.

Comment: Pode tentar ir removendo blocos de códigos(ou linhas uma a uma) do final do arquivo até o erro sumir, isso já isola um pouco o problema, fora isso não posso dizer nada exato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalizado após alterar as tag's de abertura do PHP de '

Comment: Acho que você poderia aceitar a sua resposta, e talvez elaborá-la um pouco mais.