# Erro de sintaxe php

Tags: php

Baixei um sisteminha simples de help desk, porém esta me retornando o seguinte erro após fazer o login de acesso:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\helpdesk\login.php on line 48
```

login.php

```
<?
include "config.php";
$date = date("d/m/y");
$hora = date("H:i");

@session_start(); 

if (!mysql_connect($Host, $Usuario, $Senha)) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit();
}
mysql_select_db($Base);

$user = $HTTP_POST_VARS["username"];
$pwd  = $HTTP_POST_VARS["senha"];

$sQuery = "select cod_usuario, nom_usuario, login, pwd_usuario, nivel
           from   usuarios
           where  login = '" . $user . "'";
$oUser = mysql_query($sQuery)
         or die("Query invalida: " . mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_object($oUser);
if ($num_rows = mysql_num_rows($oUser) == 1) {
    if ($row->pwd_usuario == $pwd) {
        if ($row->nivel == $Nivel) {
           $_SESSION["log_usuario"] = $user;
           $_SESSION["pwd_usuario"] = $pwd;
           $_SESSION["nom_usuario"] = $row->nom_usuario;
           $_SESSION["cod_usuario"] = $row->cod_usuario;

           $sQuery1 = "insert into acesso (cod_user, nome_user, data, hora)
             values ('" . $row->cod_usuario . "',
                     '" . $user . "',
                     '" . $date . "',
                     '" . $hora  . "')";
           mysql_query($sQuery1);
           echo "<script>window.location='index_2.php'</script>";
        } else {
               ?>
               <script language="JavaScript">
               <!--
               alert("Nivel acesso incorreto!");
               window.location = '"index.php';
               //-->
               </script>
            <?php
            } //linha do erro
    } else {
        ?>
            <script language="JavaScript">
            <!--
            alert("Senha incorreta!");
            window.location = 'index.php';
            //-->
            </script>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
        alert("Usuário não encontrado!");
        window.location = 'index.php';
        //-->
        </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Não use esse sistema, não é bom, joga fora, ele utiliza recursos removidos do php. Se puder evidenciar qual é a linha do erro ajuda muito.

Comment: Pois é, tentei várias alterações, e até pensei que o problema fosse por ele ser bem velho.

Comment: É totalmente obsoleto esse código.

Comment: Qual é a linha 48?

Comment: `@session_start();` que triste ver isso :(

Comment: Não resolve, ja vi e revi essas chaves.

Comment: O problema é na 42 em que abres um `<!--` e na linha 45 está comentado o fecho `//-->`

Comment: [Mesmo caso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112713/91)

Comment: @JorgeB. o problema é esse mesmo ou é a resposta abaixo?

Comment: @Math é um dos problemas. Mas neste caso não é causa do erro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Código PHP obsoleto, mas respondendo a sua pergunta.

No início do código você tem `<?` troque por `<?php`.

Isso ocorre porque todas as suas restantes aberturas estão utilizando `<?php`.

Experimente, coloque tudo `<?php`. Utilizar as duas no mesmo código dará o erro, que pode levar a alguns equívocos.

O seu problema, embora pareça, não tem a ver com falta de chavetas.

Isso é suficiente para dar o erro **Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}'**

Veja o seu arquivo "config.php" se não tem o mesmo problema, como está a fazer um include, o erro pode ser herdado.

Se você tem acesso as configurações do servidor, verifique o seu `php.ini`, procure pela linha `short_open_tag` e altere para "on". Reinicie o serviço do apache.

Após a configuração acima, não haverá problemas em utilizar short tags.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe é simples, faça como eu, tenha um ambiente de testes e faça o teste! Simples!

Comment: É verdade, o erro **de sintaxe** era por causa do `<?`

Comment: Por ser online, talvez exista um parse antes de o php de fato interpretar, porém, funciona sem problemas a mistura de tags: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbdc29bd7c29eebd9a9c480c2817bcf3bc38e0ab

Comment: @LuisHenrique sim mas não nesse código. O erro ocorre devido a falta do '<?php' no início.

Comment: @LuisHenrique no meu servidor não funciona o código que você postou acima. Provavelmente é alguma configuração no servidor/php. Só não entendo tantos negativos por uma resposta que é plausível.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Você está certo que está com `short_open_tag = on` no php.ini? Por exemplo, apenas `<?= "hello world" ?>` funciona no seu servidor?

Comment: @LuisHenrique sim funciona. Atenção que o servidor que você utilizou pode fazer um replace nas tags para evitar esses tipos de problemas.

Comment: Galera testei no netbeans, e ele acusa o mesmo erro de sintaxe do OP, quando se conserta a tag do php, o erro some. Foi um erro meu ao ler o código mesmo.

Comment: Reverti o downvote, mas é muito estranho isso, nunca tinha visto esse problema. Testei no meu server da amazon aqui e também funcionou o meu exemplo. E não consegui encontrar nada relacionado a isso dando uma pesquisada rápida.

Comment: @LuisHenrique tens toda razão, tinha o "short_open_tag" off, ao mudar para "on" o problema já não surge. Foi complementar a resposta.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes você poderia complementar a resposta com essa informação, só pra não deixar margens a outras interpretações equivocadas.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe completei a pergunta.