# Erro "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file"

Tags: php

Estou com problema na conexão , onde apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/html/showdospes.com.br/web/funcao/conecta.php on line 27

sendo que a linha 27 não existe só vai até a 26, qual a maneira correta de fechar o script ? aki o código:

```
<?php
function conecta( ){

  if(!defined("HOST")){
     define('HOST','localhost');
  }
  if(!defined("BD")){
     define('BD','bala');
  }
  if(!defined("USER")){
     define('USER','bombom');
  }
  if(!defined("PASS")){
     define('PASS','chocolate');
  }
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:hostname='.HOST.';dbname='.BD.';port=3306','.USER.','.PASS.');
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e -> getmessage();
}
return $conn;
}
```

Comment: você esta usando esse script ai para conectar num BD? já ouviu falar de PDO?

Comment: Não sei se foi direito mas o script É em PDO.,uso para conectar meu banco que local funciona , mas online apresenta este erro.

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [Script retornando Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51002/91)

Comment: Qual é a linha 26?

Comment: nem precisa desses "if" ai, pode tirar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teste algo assim:

```
<?php

function conecta( ) {

  if(!defined("HOST")){
     define('HOST','localhost');
  }

  if(!defined("BD")){
     define('BD','bala');
  }

  if(!defined("USER")){
     define('USER','bombom');
  }

  if(!defined("PASS")){
     define('PASS','chocolate');
  }

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:hostname='.HOST.';dbname='.BD.';port=3306', USER, PASS);
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getmessage();
    }
    return $conn;
}
```

Mudei só umas coisas no [DNS](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) não testei, mas acho que o correto é assim.

Comment: funcionou , obrigado.,Renato Tavares

Comment: Marque a resposta então como aceita.