# PHP ERRO syntax error, unexpected '>'

Tags: php

```
<?php
// começar ou retomar uma sessão
session_start();

// se vier um pedido para login
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    // estabelecer ligação com a base de dados
    mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'senha') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('u435014414_1');

    // receber o pedido de login com segurança
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

    // verificar o utilizador em questão (pretendemos obter uma única linha de registos)
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT userid, username FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");

    if ($login && mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {

        // o utilizador está correctamente validado
        // guardamos as suas informações numa sessão
        $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($login, 0, 0);
        $_SESSION['username'] = mysql_result($login, 0, 1);

        echo "<p>Sess&atilde;o iniciada com sucesso como {$_SESSION['username']}</p>
    } else {

        // falhou o login 
        echo "<p>Utilizador ou password invalidos.</p>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Olá Pedro, seja bem vindo ao stackoverflow em português, por favor, tire alguns minutos para fazer o tour e aprender mais sobre a plataforma e como fazer perguntar. [acesse o tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Feche as aspas no penúltimo echo

Comment: Você não está usando um editor php?? O Erro fica claro no editor.

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Script retornando Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51002/3635)

Comment: É um erro simples de sintaxe. Mesmo que não utilize uma IDE sofisticada, o próprio PHP da conta de apontar a linha do problema. O erro já foi apontado, acredito eu, em uma resposta. Recomendo mais atenção no código e na mensagem que indica o erro, antes de criar uma pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Existem dois erros de sintaxe no seu código.

> 1. Line : 22,   Error type : 4 Message : syntax error, unexpected '>'

Esse erro foi causado porque na linha `echo "<p>Sess&atilde;o iniciada com sucesso como {$_SESSION['username']}</p>` você deve fechar aspas e incluir um `;` no final da linha. Apos corrigir esse erro de sintaxe, ainda existe um outro erro que aparece:

> Line : 24,   Error type : 4 Message : syntax error, unexpected end of
>   file

Esse erro é causado porque falta um `}` fechando o primeiro `if (!empty($_POST)) {`.

Também tentei dar uma melhor formatada no seu código, veja se resolve:

```
<?php
// começar ou retomar uma sessão
session_start();
// se vier um pedido para login
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // estabelecer ligação com a base de dados
    mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'senhar') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('tabela');
    // receber o pedido de login com segurança
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    // verificar o utilizador em questão (pretendemos obter uma única linha de registos)
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT userid, username FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
    if ($login && mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
        // o utilizador está correctamente validado
        // guardamos as suas informações numa sessão
        $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($login, 0, 0);
        $_SESSION['username'] = mysql_result($login, 0, 1);
        echo "<p>Sess&atilde;o iniciada com sucesso como {$_SESSION['username']}</p>";
    } else {
        // falhou o login 
        echo "<p>Utilizador ou password invalidos.</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Alem disso outra recomendação... `mysql_connect` foi considerado descontinuado, use `MySQLi` ou `PDO` para se conectar ao banco.

Deixo um [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68238/14262) com leitura complementar sobre essas extensões do `php` que gerenciam conexões a um banco de dados.

Comment: Eu ia comentar o mesmo sobre o mysql_
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql