# nao estou achando o erro de syntax error, unexpected end of file in o navegador apontar na linha 88

Tags: php

```
<?php
require_once("".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/funcoes.php");
require_once("".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/mistake.php");
$whom = anti_sql($_GET["a"]);
if($whom>0){
setcookie("indicado", $whom, (time() + (86400 * 7)));
header("Location: /cadastro");
}
$logo3 = getlogo();
$progra = $mistake->query("SELECT width,height FROM Mmistake_settings WHERE name='logo'")->fetch();
echo"<center><img src='/foto/$logo3' width='$progra[0]' height='$progra[1]'></center><br/><br/><br/>"; 
$alink[0] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Uma Comunidade Diferente</b>"; 
$alink[1] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Variados Entreterimentos</b>"; 
$alink[2] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Bem vindo</b>"; 
$alink[3] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Conteudos Para Celular</b>";
$alink[4] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Venha Fazer Muitos Amigos</b>";
$alink[5] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Entre e Divirta-se é Gratuito</b>"; 
$alinks = rand(0,5);
if($_COOKIE['autologin'] == '1'){
$uidmc = anti_sql($_COOKIE['usuario']);
$uid = getuid_sid($sid);
if($uidmc>0){
$avlink = getavatarmistakepm($uidmc);
?>
<div class='postItem'> 
<headerm><big><a href='#main-nav' class='open-menu'><font color='red'>☰</font></a>
<a href='#' class='close-menu'><font color='blue'>☰</font></a></big>
<h1><a href='?'>Seja Bem Vindo <?php echo getnick_uid($uidmc);?><br/>Deseja Logar?</a></h1>
<center>
<?php echo $avlink;?><br /><br />
<form action='/login' method="POST">
<input type='text' placeholder='username' name='usuario' value='<?php echo $_COOKIE[login]; ?>' maxlength='0' title='SEU LOGIN' readonly>
<input type='password' placeholder='password' name='senha' maxlength='0' value='<?php echo $_COOKIE[senha]; ?>' title='SUA SENHA' readonly>
<br/>
Memorizar login e senha<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='ps' id='ps' value='1'/><br/>
Login Automatico?<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='autologin' id='autologin' value='1'/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='Entrar'/>
</form></center>
</headerm></div>
<?
}
}else{
?>
<div class='postItem'> 
<headerm><big><a href='#main-nav' class='open-menu'><font color='red'>☰</font></a>
<a href='#' class='close-menu'><font color='blue'>☰</font></a></big>  
<h1><a href='?'><?php echo $alink[$alinks];?><br/>Deseja Logar?</a></h1>
<center>
<ul class='lista-cmt'>
<li class='comment even thread-even depth-1' id='comment'> 
<div class='wrap-comment clearfix'>  
<div class='comment'> 
<div class='btn-reply'> 
<?
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
$modoativo = "<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://$siteurl' aria-label='Modo'>Modo Normal</a> ";
}else{
$modoativo = "<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='https://$siteurl' aria-label='Modo'>Modo Seguro</a> ";
}
?>
<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='/cadastro' aria-label='Cadastrar'>Cadastrar</a>
<?php echo $modoativo;?>
<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='/visitar' aria-label='Senha'>Redefinir Senha</a>
</div></div></div></li>
<form action='/login' method='POST'>
<img src='/login.gif'/><b>Login ou E-mail:</b><br/>
<input type='text' name='usuario' maxlength='250' placeholder='Login Ou E-mail' value='<?php echo $_COOKIE[login]; ?>'/><br/>
<img src="/senha.gif"/><b>Senha:</b><br/>
<input type='password' name='Senha' maxlength='25' placeholder='Digite Sua Senha' value='<?php echo $_COOKIE[senha]; ?>'/><br/>
Memorizar login e senha<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='ps' id='ps' value='1'/><br/>
Login Automatico?<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='autologin' id='autologin' value='1'/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='&#10150; Entrar'/></form></center>
<?
echo '</headerm></div><center>';
$sql = "SELECT id FROM Mmistake_users WHERE confirmacodigo>'0' AND avatar!='imagens/semfoto.png' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3";
$query = $mistake->query($sql);
if($query->rowCount()>0){
$x = 0;
while ($item = $query->fetch()){
echo"<a href='/perfil/".loginusuario($item[0])."'><img src='/".getavatar($item[0])."' alt='foto' style='width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:15px;margin:1px;border:3px solid #bbb;'></a>";  
$x++;
}
}
}
echo"</center>";
require_once("useronline.php");
rodape();
?>
```

Comment: Por favor não traduza as mensagens de erro. Obs: não fui eu quem negativou a pergunta.

Comment: Rosenildo, descreva sua dúvida e faça sua pergunta pois esta parecendo que você quer alguém faça o seu trabalho...

Comment: meu erro de sinttaxe na linha 88 nao estou achando

Comment: Eu te entendo, mas tenta editar a pergunta para explicar isso.

Comment: ok   ja arrumei ver se me ajudar eu agradeço

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso parece que foi os lugares que usou `<?` ao invés de `<?php`, isto porque o short_tag deve estar inativo, fora que aqui faltou os apóstrofos/aspas em `$_COOKIE[usuario]` e `$_COOKIE[senha]` (o que apenas causaria warnings):

```
<input type='text' placeholder='username' name='usuario' value='<? echo $_COOKIE[login]; ?>' maxlength='0' title='SEU LOGIN' readonly>
<input type='password' placeholder='password' name='senha' maxlength='0' value='<? echo $_COOKIE[senha]; ?>' title='SUA SENHA' readonly>
```

código ajustado:

```
<?php
require_once("".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/funcoes.php");
require_once("".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/mistake.php");
$whom = anti_sql($_GET["a"]);
if($whom>0){
setcookie("indicado", $whom, (time() + (86400 * 7)));
header("Location: /cadastro");
}
$logo3 = getlogo();
$progra = $mistake->query("SELECT width,height FROM Mmistake_settings WHERE name='logo'")->fetch();
echo"<center><img src='/foto/$logo3' width='$progra[0]' height='$progra[1]'></center><br/><br/><br/>";
$alink[0] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Uma Comunidade Diferente</b>";
$alink[1] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Variados Entreterimentos</b>";
$alink[2] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Bem vindo</b>";
$alink[3] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Conteudos Para Celular</b>";
$alink[4] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Venha Fazer Muitos Amigos</b>";
$alink[5] = "<b style='color:magenta;letter-spacing: .1px;text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #111, 1px 1px 1px #000;'>Entre e Divirta-se é Gratuito</b>";
$alinks = rand(0,5);
if($_COOKIE['autologin'] == '1'){
$uidmc = anti_sql($_COOKIE['usuario']);
$uid = getuid_sid($sid);
if($uidmc>0){
$avlink = getavatarmistakepm($uidmc);
?>
<div class='postItem'>
<headerm><big><a href='#main-nav' class='open-menu'><font color='red'>☰</font></a>
<a href='#' class='close-menu'><font color='blue'>☰</font></a></big>
<h1><a href='?'>Seja Bem Vindo <?phpphp echo getnick_uid($uidmc);?><br/>Deseja Logar?</a></h1>
<center>
<?phpphp echo $avlink;?><br /><br />
<form action='/login' method="POST">
<input type='text' placeholder='username' name='usuario' value='<?phpphp echo $_COOKIE[login]; ?>' maxlength='0' title='SEU LOGIN' readonly>
<input type='password' placeholder='password' name='senha' maxlength='0' value='<?phpphp echo $_COOKIE[senha]; ?>' title='SUA SENHA' readonly>
<br/>
Memorizar login e senha<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='ps' id='ps' value='1'/><br/>
Login Automatico?<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='autologin' id='autologin' value='1'/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='Entrar'/>
</form></center>
</headerm></div>
<?php
}
}else{
?>
<div class='postItem'>
<headerm><big><a href='#main-nav' class='open-menu'><font color='red'>☰</font></a>
<a href='#' class='close-menu'><font color='blue'>☰</font></a></big>
<h1><a href='?'><?phpphp echo $alink[$alinks];?><br/>Deseja Logar?</a></h1>
<center>
<ul class='lista-cmt'>
<li class='comment even thread-even depth-1' id='comment'>
<div class='wrap-comment clearfix'>
<div class='comment'>
<div class='btn-reply'>
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
$modoativo = "<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://$siteurl' aria-label='Modo'>Modo Normal</a> ";
}else{
$modoativo = "<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='https://$siteurl' aria-label='Modo'>Modo Seguro</a> ";
}
?>
<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='/cadastro' aria-label='Cadastrar'>Cadastrar</a>
<?phpphp echo $modoativo;?>
<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='/visitar' aria-label='Senha'>Redefinir Senha</a>
</div></div></div></li>
<form action='/login' method='POST'>
<img src='/login.gif'/><b>Login ou E-mail:</b><br/>
<input type='text' name='usuario' maxlength='250' placeholder='Login Ou E-mail' value='<?phpphp echo $_COOKIE['login']; ?>'/><br/>
<img src="/senha.gif"/><b>Senha:</b><br/>
<input type='password' name='Senha' maxlength='25' placeholder='Digite Sua Senha' value='<?phpphp echo $_COOKIE['senha']; ?>'/><br/>
Memorizar login e senha<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='ps' id='ps' value='1'/><br/>
Login Automatico?<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='autologin' id='autologin' value='1'/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='&#10150; Entrar'/></form></center>
<?php
echo '</headerm></div><center>';
$sql = "SELECT id FROM Mmistake_users WHERE confirmacodigo>'0' AND avatar!='imagens/semfoto.png' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3";
$query = $mistake->query($sql);
if($query->rowCount()>0){
$x = 0;
while ($item = $query->fetch()){
echo"<a href='/perfil/".loginusuario($item[0])."'><img src='/".getavatar($item[0])."' alt='foto' style='width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:15px;margin:1px;border:3px solid #bbb;'></a>";
$x++;
}
}
}
echo"</center>";
require_once("useronline.php");
rodape();
?>
```

> **Nota:** realmente acho que deveria pensar em identar melhor teu código como expliquei nesta resposta [Script retornando Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51003/3635)

Comment: ainda deu erro outro

Comment: @ROSENILDOBARROSDEALMEIDA qual erro? "Ainda deu erro outro" não é informação o suficiente para entendermos.