# Formulário não envia email para outro servidor fora da hospedagem

Tags: php, email, mailer

Estou desenvolvendo um site com formulário de contato. O `form` é bem simples apenas com os campos nome, email, mensagem e assunto.

Eu tenho o site hospedado num servidor, mas preciso que os dados do `form` sejam recebidos em uma conta de email em outro servidor, não o que está configurado no serviço de hospedagem.

Eu tentei pela função mail do php e não deu certo, tentei usar a classe PHPMailer e ocorreu um erro relacionado com STMP: 
(SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Não foi possível enviar a mensagem. Erro: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.)

**Deu o seguinte erro:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /home/trweb146/public_html/desenvolvimento/FormEmailPHPMailer/enviar.php
>   on line 61

```
$erros = "";

if(empty($_POST['nome'])){ $erros .= "O nome deve ser preenchidooo."; }

if(empty($_POST['email']) ){ $erros .= "O E-mail deve ser preenchido."; }else{ $mail = $_POST['email']; /eregi("([._0-9A-Za-z-]+)@([0-9A-Za-z-]+)(.[0-9A-Za-z.]+)",$email,$match); if(!isset($match)){ $erros .= "O e-mail informado é inválido."; }/ }

if(empty($_POST['mensagem'])){ $erros .= "A mensagem deve ser preenchida."; }

if( empty($erros) ){

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP();

try{
    $mail->Host = "smtp.trwebsites.com.br";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Port     = 587;
    $mail->Username = "contato@trwebsites.com.br";
    $mail->Password = "*****";//aqui coloquei a senha do meu email

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
//remetente $mail->SetFrom("contato@trwebsites.com.br", "Nome Empresa"); //$mail->AddReplyTo("webmaster@seudominio.com.br", "Nome Empresa"); $mail->Subject = "Um assunto";

    //destinatários
    $mail->AddAddress($this->emailDestinatario, "nome destinatário");
    $mail->AddCC($this->emailCopia, "Cópia pra fulano");

    $conteudo = "-- Dados --<br/>";
//corpo do e-mail $mail->MsgHTML($conteudo);

    $mail->Send();

    return true;

}catch(phpmailerException $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
    return false;
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Já passei por isso, no meu caso era porque o e-mail que eu estava usando pra enviar deveria ser um da hospedagem. Por exemplo, você tem que criar um email@seudominio.com e usar ele pra enviar.

Comment: "O remetente deve ser um e-mail do seu domínio conforme determina a RFC 822.". Quanto ao SMTP, que inclusive você só consegue enviar e-mail pra Outlook e Cia. usando ele, provavelmente seu host é smtp.dominio.com.br.

Comment: Jhonatan Pereira - Não tenho como utilizar emails da mesma hospedagem do site, os emails estão em uma hospedagem fora do servidor do site.

Comment: Jhonatan Pereira - Não entendi, você disse que "Quanto ao SMTP, que inclusive você só consegue enviar e-mail pra Outlook e Cia.", não posso enviar e-mails para uma conta da Hostgator por exemplo? Se sim, qual a configuração devo utilizar você sabe me dizer?

Comment: Você não entendeu. Digamos que você tem que mandar e-mail para empresa@gmail.com. Pra enviar pra eles têm que partir de algum e-mail (o remetente). O remetente talvez tenha que ser um e-mail do domínio hospedado, isso só sua hospedagem pode confirmar. Atualiza a pergunta e Posta seu código, fica mais fácil pra ajudar.

Comment: O Outlook, Hotmail, MSN e etc da Microsoft só recebem os e-mail se for por SMTP. Enviar usando a função mail() o destinatário não recebe. Não que o SMTP só envie pra esses, ele envia pra todos os servidores de e-mail.

Comment: O erro que você mostrou (unexpected end of file) indica que tem algum caracter que foi aberto mas não foi fechado. Pode ser aspas, chaves, algo assim. No código que mostrou não encontrei erro, estava linha 61, verifica próximo a ela

Comment: Ou 61 é a última linha do arquivo, porque ele encontrou um fim inesperado. Está usando algum editor de código? O Bracket Editor facilita muito pra achar esses problemas.

Comment: Troque o `<?` por `<?php`, isso é erro de sintaxe porque o seu servidor desabilitou o short_tags do PHP, mais detalhes em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51003/3635 (procure o trecho que falo de `Misturar tags PHP (<?php) com short_open_tag (<?)`)

Answer (score 1):

Usa o SMTP mesmo, verifica as configurações:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP();

try{
    $mail->Host = "smtp.seudominio.com.br";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Port     = 587;
    $mail->Username = "webmaster@seudominio.com.br";
    $mail->Password = "Senha";

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    //remetente
    $mail->SetFrom("webmaster@seudominio.com.br", "Nome Empresa");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("webmaster@seudominio.com.br", "Nome Empresa");
    $mail->Subject = "Um assunto";

    //destinatários
    $mail->AddAddress($this->emailDestinatario, "nome destinatário");
    $mail->AddCC($this->emailCopia, "Cópia pra fulano");

    $conteudo = "-- Dados --<br/>";

    //corpo do e-mail
    $mail->MsgHTML($conteudo);

    $mail->Send();

    return true;

}catch(phpmailerException $e){
    echo $e->errorMessage();
    return false;
}
```