# Salvar imagem junto com formulário para o banco de dados por PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde gente, galera me ajudem por favor, eu achei um tutorial na internet que ensina a salvar a imagem no banco de dados com php e jquery, mas ele ensina enviar só a imagem ja tentei de toda forma possíveis para eu colocar com formulário com nome e sexo por exemplo mas não consigo acredito que por eu ser iniciante... Poderiam me ajudar? Segue os códigos

**Banco**

```
 CREATE TABLE `fotos` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nome` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `conteudo` mediumblob NOT NULL,
 `tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `tamanho` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Cadastro**

```
// Quando enviado o formulário
$('#formulario').on('submit', function () {

    // Armazenando objetos em variáveis para utilizá-los posteriormente
    var formulario = $(this);
    var botao = $('#salvar');
    var mensagem = $('#mensagem');

    // Exibindo indicador de carregamento (Bootstrap)
    // Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons
    botao.button('loading');

    // Enviando formulário
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({

        // Definindo tipo de retorno do servidor
        dataType: 'json',

        // Se a requisição foi um sucesso
        success: function (retorno) {

            // Se cadastrado com sucesso
            if (retorno.sucesso) {
                // Definindo estilo da mensagem (sucesso)
                mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-success');

                // Limpando formulário
                formulario.resetForm();
            }
            else {
                // Definindo estilo da mensagem (erro)
                mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
            }

            // Exibindo mensagem
            mensagem.html(retorno.mensagem);

            // Escondendo indicador de carregamento
            botao.button('reset');

        },

        // Se houver algum erro na requisição
        error: function () {

            // Definindo estilo da mensagem (erro)
            mensagem.attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');

            // Exibindo mensagem
            mensagem.html(retorno.mensagem);

            // Escondendo indicador de carregamento
            botao.button('reset');
        }

    });

    // Retorna FALSE para que o formulário não seja enviado de forma convencional
    return false;

});
<form id="formulario" action="ajax/salvar.php" method="post">

    <div id="mensagem"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Foto</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="foto"/>
    </div>

    <input id="salvar" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar" data-loading-text="Salvando..."/>

</form>
```

**Conexao**

Não vou colocar é padrão

**Util**

```
<?php

// Função que retorno um JSON com a propriedade sucesso e mensagem
function retorno($mensagem, $sucesso = false)
{
    // Criando vetor com a propriedades
    $retorno = array();
    $retorno['sucesso'] = $sucesso;
    $retorno['mensagem'] = $mensagem;

    // Convertendo para JSON e retornando
    return json_encode($retorno);
}
```

**Salvar**

```
<?php
// Incluindo arquivo de conexão
require_once('../config/conn.php');

// Funções de utilidade
require_once('../funcs/util.php');

// Constantes
define('TAMANHO_MAXIMO', (2 * 1024 * 1024));

// Verificando se selecionou alguma imagem
if (!isset($_FILES['foto']))
{
    echo retorno('Selecione uma imagem');
    exit;
}

// Recupera os dados dos campos
$foto = $_FILES['foto'];
$nome = $foto['name'];
$tipo = $foto['type'];
$tamanho = $foto['size'];

// Validações básicas
// Formato
if(!preg_match('/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/', $tipo))
{
    echo retorno('Isso não é uma imagem válida');
    exit;
}

// Tamanho
if ($tamanho > TAMANHO_MAXIMO)
{
    echo retorno('A imagem deve possuir no máximo 2 MB');
    exit;
}

// Transformando foto em dados (binário)
$conteudo = file_get_contents($foto['tmp_name']);

// Preparando comando
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO fotos (nome, conteudo, tipo, tamanho) VALUES (:nome, :conteudo, :tipo, :tamanho)');

// Definindo parâmetros
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':conteudo', $conteudo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->bindParam(':tipo', $tipo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':tamanho', $tamanho, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Executando e exibindo resultado
echo ($stmt->execute()) ? retorno('Foto cadastrada com sucesso', true) : retorno($stmt->errorInfo());
```

**Index**

```
    <?php
    // Incluindo arquivo de conexão
    require_once('config/conn.php');

    // Selecionando fotos
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, nome, tipo, tamanho FROM fotos');
    ?>
<div class="row">

        <?php while ($foto = $stmt->fetchObject()): ?>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">

                <div class="thumbnail">

                    <img src="imagem.php?id=<?php echo $foto->id ?>" />

                    <div class="caption">
                        <strong>Nome:</strong> <?php echo $foto->nome ?> <br/>
                        <strong>Tipo:</strong> <?php echo $foto->tipo ?> <br/>
                        <strong>Tamanho:</strong> <?php echo $foto->tamanho ?> bytes <br/>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile ?>

    </div>
```

**Creditos:**

**http://rafaelcouto.com.br/salvar-imagem-no-banco-de-dados-com-php-mysql/**

**Me ajudem por favor**

Comment: Qual o erro que você está recebendo?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42886/salvar-no-banco-de-dados-o-conte%C3%BAdo-bin%C3%A1rio-de-uma-imagem

Comment: nenhum erro, eu quero alem de salvar a imagem salvar o nome da pessoa e sexo dela

Comment: Insira `error_reporting(E_ALL);` logo no início da página salvar (logo após `<?php`, e veja se aparece algum erro. Tenta também debugar estas páginas, pra ver se encontra o problema.

Comment: Use o tipo BLOB no mysql

Comment: Mas você quer salvar esses dados (nome, sexo, etc...) aonde... no DB da imagem ou em outro DB... essa é a questão. Alem disso, seria importante você postar aqui o formulário aonde é inserida essa imagem.