# Upload de imagem mysql

Tags: php, mysql, upload, imagem

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para desenvolver um código para armazenar imagens no banco de dados, até o momento não consegui nada... Não sei se é melhor armazenar o arquivo em um diretório e somente o nome no bd, e principalmente como fazer isto...

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="cadastrar.php">
<table>
<tr><td>imagem:</td><td><input type="file" size="60" name="arq" value=""></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

```php
$arq_name = $_FILES['arq']['name']; //nome do arquivo
$arq_size = $_FILES['arq']['size']; //tamanho do arquivo
$arq_tmp = $_FILES['arq']['tmp_name']; //nome temporário do arquivo

//grava no DB
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (foto) VALUES ('$arq_name')");
//grava a img no diretório
move_uploaded_file($arq_tmp, "imagens/".$arq_name);
```

Agora só tenho que conseguir buscar as imagens pelo id...

Comment: o que vc ja tentou amigo?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, vê se você entendeu...

Comment: Leia isto - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42886/salvar-no-banco-de-dados-o-conte%C3%BAdo-bin%C3%A1rio-de-uma-imagem

Comment: Então, eu não sei se ficaria melhor em um diretorio ou no proprio db...

Comment: Leia as respostas desse _link_, em atenção à última que possui algumas boas referências sobre o uso, e depois talvez consigas saber qual usar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruno, a pratica mais comum é o armazenamento da imagem em diretório e armazenamento apenas do caminho em BD, do contrário, precisará pesquisar mais a fundo sobre dados do tipo blob. Da forma que está fazendo, conseguirá assim:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="cadastrar.php">
<table>
<tr><td>imagem:</td><td><input type="file" size="60" name="arq" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" size="60" name="enviar" value="Upload"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

cadastrar.php

```
if($_POST["enviar"]) {

    $tempname = $_FILES["arq"]["tmp_name"];
    $new_name = uniqid(); // Novo nome aleatório do arquivo
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["arq"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Pega extensão de arquivo e converte em caracteres minúsculos.      
    $folder = "imagens"; // Pasta onde será armazenada a imagem.

    if(move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder."/".$new_name.".".$extension)) { // Move arquivo para a pasta em questão e com o novo nome.
        // Grava no DB
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (foto) VALUES ('$new_name.".".$extension')");
        echo "Arquivo enviado com sucesso.";
    } else echo "Erro ao enviar arquivo.";
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Thyago, agora entendi muito bem :D

Comment: @BrunoFerreira estamos aí, disponha... =)