# Gerar byte array de imagem para inserir no BD

Tags: php, array, byte

Preciso salvar uma imagem jpg no banco de dados em uma coluna BLOB, porem, tudo o que tentei não deu certo, o que estou testando agora para tentar gerar o byte array é isso:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$filename = $file['tmp_name'];
$byteArrayFile = ""; 
$fhandle = fopen($filename, "rb");
    while (!feof($fhandle)) {
        $data = fread($fhandle, 1);
        // array_push($byteArrayFile, $data);
        $byteArrayFile .= $data;
    }
fclose($fhandle);
```

E para inserir no bd estou tentando algo assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABELA(campo_blob) VALUES('{$byteArrayFile}')";
```

Mas como escrevi no inicio, nada deu certo, alguem sabe a forma correta de salvar a imagem no bd em coluna BLOB ?

Obrigado.

Comment: [Veja](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42886/salvar-no-banco-de-dados-o-conte%C3%BAdo-bin%C3%A1rio-de-uma-imagem)

Comment: Seria bom dizer qual é o BD usado. De qq forma, ler arquivo byte a byte é péssimo, e trabalhar com o memory_limit assim é gambi. De qualquer forma, esta leitura que você está fazendo tem numa das respostas da original indicada no fechamento, dê uma olhada nelas. Se seu caso for diferente daquele, edite a pergunta com os detalhes relevantes e deixe um comentário.

Comment: O BD é Mysql, mas a resposta para a pergunta já existe e resolveu meu problema! (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42886/salvar-no-banco-de-dados-o-conte%C3%BAdo-bin%C3%A1rio-de-uma-imagem)

Obrigado!