# Como criar um armazenador de arquivos?

Tags: html5, css3, phpmyadmin

Como faço para criar um armazenador de arquivos?

**Exemplo:**

A pessoa quer salvar um arquivo PDF no meu site, ai ela vai lá, clica no botão de enviar arquivo e fica salvo no meu sistema. E quando ela acessar, ela pode ir lá e baixar o arquivo que ela salvou.

**Tipo agora, que fui colocar essa imagem na publicação...**

*Vai ser open, qualquer um que acessar vai poder fazer o download dos arquivos.*

[image: Aqui está a imagem do menu do site]

Comment: Você precisa salvar os arquivos em algum lugar. Na nuvem, no disco do seu servidor ou num banco de dados.

Comment: No caso, quero salvar no banco de dados. No PHPMyadmin do VertrigoServ. É possível?! Né? Porque não vão ser muitos arquivos, tudo em pdf praticamente...

Comment: Veja se isto resolve: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42886/salvar-no-banco-de-dados-o-conte%C3%BAdo-bin%C3%A1rio-de-uma-imagem

Comment: A resposta de @bfavaretto é válida, porém sua pergunta é como fazer um sistema de armazenamento ou como inserir um arquivo no mysql sem salvar em ftp?

Comment: É mais em relação a fazer um sistema de armazenamento. Por exemplo... O álbum de imagens do facebook, você não clica em um botão, escolhe a foto e envia? Ai ele salva e fica lá na sua pasta... É tipo isso, mas com arquivos PDF :v